# How do I call context become outside of a Future from Ask messages?

Tags: scala, akka

I have a parent akka actor named `buildingCoordinator` which creates childs name `elevator_X`. For now I am creating only one `elevator`. The `buildingCoordinator` sends a sequence of messages and wait for responses in order to move an `elevator`. The sequence is this: sends  `? RequestElevatorState` -> receive `ElevatorState` -> sends `? MoveRequest` -> receives `MoveRequestSuccess` -> changes the state. As you can see I am using the `ask` pattern. After the movement is successes the `buildingCoordinator` changes its state using `context.become`.

The problem that I am running is that the elevator is receiving `MoveRequest(1,4)` for the same floor twice, sometimes three times. I do remove the floor when I call `context.become`. However I remove inside the last `map`. I think it is because I am using `context.become` inside a future and I should use it outside. But I am having trouble implementing it.

```
case class BuildingCoordinator(actorName: String,
                               numberOfFloors: Int,
                               numberOfElevators: Int,
                               elevatorControlSystem: ElevatorControlSystem)
  extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import context.dispatcher
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(4 seconds)
  val elevators = createElevators(numberOfElevators)

  override def receive: Receive = operational(Map[Int, Queue[Int]](), Map[Int, Queue[Int]]())

  def operational(stopsRequests: Map[Int, Queue[Int]], pickUpRequests: Map[Int, Queue[Int]]): Receive = {
    case msg@MoveElevator(elevatorId) =>
      println(s"[BuildingCoordinator] received $msg")
      val elevatorActor: ActorSelection = context.actorSelection(s"/user/$actorName/elevator_$elevatorId")
      val newState = (elevatorActor ? RequestElevatorState(elevatorId))
        .mapTo[ElevatorState]
        .flatMap { state =>
          val nextStop = elevatorControlSystem.findNextStop(stopsRequests.get(elevatorId).get, state.currentFloor, state.direction)
          elevatorActor ? MoveRequest(elevatorId, nextStop)
        }
        .mapTo[MoveRequestSuccess]
        .flatMap(moveRequestSuccess => elevatorActor ? MakeMove(elevatorId, moveRequestSuccess.targetFloor))
        .mapTo[MakeMoveSuccess]
        .map { makeMoveSuccess =>
          println(s"[BuildingCoordinator] Elevator ${makeMoveSuccess.elevatorId} arrived at floor [${makeMoveSuccess.floor}]")
          // removeStopRequest
          val stopsRequestsElevator = stopsRequests.get(elevatorId).getOrElse(Queue[Int]())
          val newStopsRequestsElevator = stopsRequestsElevator.filterNot(_ == makeMoveSuccess.floor)
          val newStopsRequests = stopsRequests + (elevatorId -> newStopsRequestsElevator)

          val pickUpRequestsElevator = pickUpRequests.get(elevatorId).getOrElse(Queue[Int]())
          val newPickUpRequestsElevator = {
            if (pickUpRequestsElevator.contains(makeMoveSuccess.floor)) {
              pickUpRequestsElevator.filterNot(_ == makeMoveSuccess.floor)
            } else {
              pickUpRequestsElevator
            }
          }
          val newPickUpRequests = pickUpRequests + (elevatorId -> newPickUpRequestsElevator)
          // I THINK I SHOULD NOT CALL context.become HERE
          // context.become(operational(newStopsRequests, newPickUpRequests))

          val dropOffFloor = BuildingUtil.generateRandomFloor(numberOfFloors, makeMoveSuccess.floor, makeMoveSuccess.direction)
          context.self ! DropOffRequest(makeMoveSuccess.elevatorId, dropOffFloor)

          (newStopsRequests, newPickUpRequests)
        }
      // I MUST CALL context.become HERE, BUT I DONT KNOW HOW
      // context.become(operational(newState.flatMap(state => (state._1, state._2))))
  }
```

Other thing that might be nasty here is this big chain of `map` and `flatMap`. This was my way to implement, however I think it might exist one way better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't and you should not call `context.become` or anyhow change actor state outside `Receive` method and outside `Receive` method invoke thread (which is Akka distpatcher thread), like in your example. Eg:

```
def receive: Receive  = {
   // This is a bug, because context is not and is not supposed to be thread safe.
   case message: Message => Future(context.become(anotherReceive))
}
```

What you should do - send message to `self` after async operation finished and change the state receive after. If in a mean time you don't want to handle incoming messages - you can stash them. See for more details: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/stash.html

High level example, technical details omitted:

```
case OperationFinished(calculations: Map[Any, Any])

class AsyncActor extends Actor with Stash {

 def operation: Future[Map[Any, Any]] = ...//some implementation of heavy async operation

 def receiveStartAsync(calculations: Map[Any, Any]): Receive =  {
   case StartAsyncOperation => 
     //Start async operation and inform yourself that it is finished
     operation.map(OperationFinished.apply) pipeTo self
     context.become(receiveWaitAsyncOperation)
 }

 def receiveWaitAsyncOperation: Receive = {
   case OperationFinished => 
     unstashAll()
     context.become(receiveStartAsync)

   case _ => stash()
 }
}
```

Comment: hi, actually I solved the problem by not calling the `.mapTo` operation which is non-blocking, and using a `Await` like it is explained here (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/futures.html#use-with-actors). Nevertheless your answer is also true and I will test it. Thanks

Comment: @Felipe I'd Strongly do not recommend go with Await for a lot of reasons. I just had very hard times, because of await in Receive method. Save your future time and don't do this!

Comment: I am using stash and unstash inside the elevator actor and indeed it is an alternative to not use `Await` together with the `ask` pattern.

Comment: If I use a Await with infinite duration it will never timeout and hence work as stash and unstash, won't it? Can you give some detail why I can run into problems using Await? I mean, I agree with you that stash is better and more elegant. I am just wondering what could go wrong....

Comment: Because Await is blocking, meaning while you block one of AKKA's thread, which responsible for message delivery between actors. Which means not only your actor but other might receive their message not in time, which can lead to timeouts in another unexpected places. In our particular case it was time out as well, leading to some random jobs stuck. This is like of 100 reasons to not block Akka dispatcher thread.

Comment: @Felipe See: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/dispatchers.html#blocking-needs-careful-management

Answer (score 2):

I like your response @Ivan Kurchenko.
But, according to: [Akka Stash docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/stash.html)

> When unstashing the buffered messages by calling unstashAll the messages will be processed sequentially in the order they were added and all are processed unless an exception is thrown. The actor is unresponsive to other new messages until unstashAll is completed. That is another reason for keeping the number of stashed messages low. Actors that hog the message processing thread for too long can result in starvation of other actors.

Meaning that under load, for example, the `unstashAll` operation will cause all other Actors to be in starvation.

According to the same doc:

> That can be mitigated by using the StashBuffer.unstash with numberOfMessages parameter and then send a message to context.self before continuing unstashing more. That means that other new messages may arrive in-between and those must be stashed to keep the original order of messages. It becomes more complicated, so better keep the number of stashed messages low.

Bottom line: you should keep the stashed message count low. It might be not suitable for load operation.